# Validate input to a POST request?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, controller, json-schema-validator

I have made a controller for a REST POST api endpoint, is as following

```
public IActionResult POST([FromBody]Person person) 
{ 
    ....
}
```

and where Person is defined as

```
public class Person 
{
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public int Age {get; set;}
}
```

meaning that the post request is able deserialise an input like this

```
{
  "Name": "Peter", 
  "Age": 2
}
```

without any problems...

Problems occurs though when I pass something like

```
{
  "Name": "Peter", 
  "Age": 2, 
  "Error": 123123123
}
```

It still creates an `Person` which have the first two filled out..

I would like to trigger an error here stating that the input format is wrong.

I am storing the first input - and then use it to compare the next input based on the first one. 
If they are the same - nothing should happen.

But since the last input contains a invalid field but the actual instance the input created is completely similar to the first one - I get an error on they are not equal?

I assume the `error` statement in the JSON is somehow stored in the new instance? 
but how do i make sure that the input is being validated before the controller created an instance given the JSON input?

Comment: Do you use core or standard mvc project?

Comment: @IvanSmyrnov I am using Core

Answer (score 0):

1) to validate your Person model, you could have something like

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
public class Person
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(250, MinimumLength = 2)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Range(1, 121)]
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

and inside controller's POST action you can use `if(!ModelState.IsValid){.....}`

2) to compare if two Person instances are equal you could override Equals():

```
public class Person
{
    ...
    ...
    public override bool Equals(object obj) =>
        (obj is Person otherPerson) ? (Name,Age) == (otherPerson.Name,otherPerson.Age): false;
}
```

here current instance's Name and Age are compared to other instance's Name and Age. It will allow using `if ( person.Equals ( someOtherPErsonInstance ) ){....}`

3) if you need to make sure extra fields **are not** present in the POST request, you could add custom implementation IModelBinder, or accept raw data in POST action, then, parse and check.